# Can you stick one div to the bottom of another div?

Tags: html, css

I am building this website for work but I am having a slight problem. I thought it was a good idea to have a header, followed by a rotating banner and then the text but have only the text move when the page is scrolled. It is working fine on my monitor in full screen but I am trying to make it responsive so obviously on a smaller screen, the banner shrink but the div with the text in is still the same number of pixels from the top. This leaves an unappealing space in between the two.

Anyway here is my html:

```
<div id="banner"><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script> <img class="active" src="Images/banner1.jpg"> <img src=
    "Images/banner4.jpg"> <img src="Images/banner2.jpg"> <img src=
    "Images/banner3.jpg"> <img src="Images/banner5.jpg"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            //Get current active image
            var active = $('#banner .active');

            // If there is another image(object) left then make that image next
            // If not, go back to the first image of the banner div
            if (active.next().length > 0) var next = active.next();
            else var next = $('#banner img:first');

            //Get the next image ready by modifying the z-index
            next.css('z-index', '2');

            //Fade out the active image, then
            active.fadeOut(1000, function () {
            //Move the active image to the back of the pile, show it and remove the active class
            active.css('z-index', '1').show().removeClass('active');
            //Make the next image the active one  
            next.css('z-index', '3').addClass('active');
            });


        }, 3000);
        });

        </script> <!--BANNER FINISH-->


        <div id="content">
            <div class="maintext">
                <h1>Welcome to InstaGuard security</h1>

            </br>

                <p>We are installers of temporary security systems. </p>
            </div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#banner {
    width: 100%;
    top: 181px;
    position: absolute;
}

#banner img {
    position: fixed;
    z-index:1;
    width: 100%;
}

#banner img.active {
    z-index:3;  
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    top: 681px; 
    height: 1000px;
    z-index: 70;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding-top: 0.5%;
}

.maintext {
    text-align: center;
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Is it possible to 'stick' the 'content' div to the bottom of the 'banner' div so that they move together? I would be very grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: I didn't find any `banner` there

Comment: Can you please provide JSBin or fiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

By setting the parent container to `position: relative` and it's child to

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

you will always have the child at the bottom of the parent.

Matching your example:

```
#banner {
    position: relative;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Basic example in Codepen: http://codepen.io/Nice2MeatU/pen/avvGRO

Comment: Here is the JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eceqk6pq/4/

This is what it looks like at the moment: http://imgur.com/SXlsBmn

When I make the banner relative and the content absolute, this is what happens: http://imgur.com/ZYY2XoL

Comment: I updated my comment with a codepen to show you what I mean. May be that can shed a light. =)

Answer (score 0):

Check This Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xDZPK/135/) Link

CSS code:

```
#banner {
    position: relative;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
}
```